# Custom Jersey injections

Tags: java, rest, jersey, code-injection

I can't find the right way to inject objects in jersey resource.

I have defined this provider:

```
@Provider
public class UpsellPaymentProvider implements InjectableProvider<Context, UpsellPaymentService>{

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    
    public UpsellPaymentProvider(){
        log.info("Provider is instanced");
    }
    
    @Override
    public ComponentScope getScope() {
        return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public Injectable<UpsellPaymentService> getInjectable(ComponentContext paramComponentContext,
            Context paramA, UpsellPaymentService paramC) {
        log.info("Injecting UpsellPaymentService");
        return new AbstractHttpContextInjectable<UpsellPaymentService>() {
            @Override
            public UpsellPaymentService getValue(HttpContext arg0) {
                return new UpsellPaymentService();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

As you can see in the next code, I have a `UpsellPaymentService` that should be provided by `UpsellPaymentProvider`:

```
@Path("/rest/payment/upsell")
public class UpsellResource {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    @Context // Inject here
    private UpsellPaymentService upsellPaymentService;
    
    @POST
    @Path("/first")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response first(@InjectParam UpsellDto dto, Form allParams){
        // code here
    }
    
}
```

When I run a test, I can see that the provider and the resource is discovered, but it seems that provider doesn't inject:

> INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
> example.ws.resources   example.ws.providers
>
> 11-oct-2013 13:19:34 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
> INFO: Root resource classes found:   class
> example.ws.resources.UpsellResource
>
> 11-oct-2013 13:19:34 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
> INFO: Provider classes found:   class
> example.ws.providers.UpsellPaymentProvider
>
> ...Not important logs...
>
> 2013-10-11 13:19:35,092 INFO  example.ws.providers.UpsellPaymentProvider.(29)--->
> Provider is instanced
>
> 11-oct-2013 13:19:36 com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
>
> GRAVE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with
> resource and/or provider classes:
>
> SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private
> example.ws.services.UpsellPaymentService
> example.ws.resources.UpsellResource.upsellPaymentService

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, changing **UpsellPaymentService** (second generic of InjectableProvider) by **Type**.